# Visible or not models in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, boolean

I have a model, with the `is_visible`.
Depending on whether this option is selected or not want the data from the model shown in the front-end.
How to do it?

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Do it like that. Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to select only the users who are visible:

```
users = MyUser.objects.exclude(is_visible=False)
```

or inversely:

```
users = MyUser.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
```

in your template, you can check the property:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if not user.is_visible %}
        {# do something here #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and be sure to read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#filter) method to get list of visible users:

```
visible_users = MyUser.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
```